# GCC static linking error for lpthread

Tags: gcc

My gcc command below outputs a lot of errors, I want to static link all libraries into my app.

```
/usr/bin/c++ -g /home/dean/work/jiangshu-sports-lottery/builder/o/displays.cpp.o ... -o bin/sports_lottery -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread.a -lcppcms.a -lmongoclient.a -lbooster.a -lloki.a -lcryptopp.a -lboost_system.a -lboost_thread.a -lboost_filesystem.a
```

I saw one of error is about pthread, that is:

> /usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lpthread.a

but when I dynamic link it, no error. the location of libpthread on my Ubuntu is found below:

```
find / -name 'libpthread.*'
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
```

Any help? I am looking for some GCC documents for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
-lpthread
```

to include static libraries, which are in the standard search paths. If you really want to use the absolute path to your library (which should not be the case using pthreads) you can use the `-L` switch and give it the absolute path to your library.

Here some reference documentation:

[gcc Online documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Comment: but some people said -pthread was correct and -lpthread was wrong

Comment: @DeanChen `-pthread` is a convenience option that sets certain options for both the pre-processor and linking stage, where `-lpthread` simply specifies linking with that specific library, regardless of whether you did the right things in the pre-processor and compiler stages. I would suggest using both (but the `-lpthread` may be redundant). In either case, the `-l<lib>` syntax looks for either `lib<lib>.a` or `lib<lib>.so`, depending on whether you're linking static or not - specifying `-l<lib>.a` makes it look for `lib<lib>.a.a`, which it won't find...

Comment: After adjusting my dependencies order, I made it, with -pthread.